# how to convert partition collection to non-partition in azure Document Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way to convert partition collection to non-partition collection in azure Document Db and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a collection between partitioned and non-partitioned. Partition keys are defined when partitioned collections are created and cannot be added (or removed) later.

To shift from non-partitioned to partitioned (or from partitioned to non-partitioned), you'll need to copy the data between two collections (this is called out specifically in the DocumentDB guidance published [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-things-to-know-about-documentdb-partitioned-collections/)).

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the non-partitioned collections have a limit on storage and throughput. If you are ok with limiting to 10 GB and restrict the throughput within 10000 RUPS, then you could copy the data back to non-partitioned collection.

You could alternatively start with a partitioned collection with minimal throughput. This way if your scale needs change, your partitioning is in place.

Feel free to contact Azure support if you want the default limits to be adjusted - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-increase-limits/